# Moving data between Azure Blob storeage and Azure database on demand

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a project with a requirement to process data from an Azure blob to an Azure database on demand.  We are headed down the path of using the Azure Data Factory, but the more I read up on it, the more I'm not convinced that's the way to go.  I have two concerns:

1. It looks like everything needs to be scheduled in ADF, the only way I've seen to do an on demand process is by using the isPaused property.
2. Concurrency - it's possible that multiple users will be running the process at the same time.  I've coded this up before with SSIS packages, but never ADF.  Is this even possible?

This just seems like the wrong tool for the process, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) is a perfectly good tool but you need to think about things a bit differently.  In somes ways it is like SSIS, but in many ways it is not.  Particularly as an ELT and orchestration tool not an ETL tool (like SSIS) transforms are done elsewhere, normally on the compute you are running on and not in the ADF pipeline.

The scheduling is modelled around [slices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution) which is an important subject to understand with ADF.  With your example, you could have directories named after the year with sub-directories of the month, with sub-directories of the day etc right down to whatever level you need.  Set your frequency to match, eg month, day, hour etc, then ADF would create slices for each time slice and run accordingly.  Re the concurrency, multiple users could drop their files in the blob storage and ADF would process each one, say every 15 minutes.  This is just another way of approaching the same problem, make sense?

You always have the option of running SSIS in the cloud, obviously you'll need a VM (IaaS) to run it on.  There is the SSIS [Azure Feature Pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt146770.aspx) which has Azure Blob Source and Destination, so it would be easy to do what you need.